# Relation of $e$ to other numbers...

Tags: number-theory, inequality, exponential-function, exponentiation

I found the following result,
When i was working on my calculator
.
$$x^y < y^x \quad  ,x < y \quad \text{ for } x,y<e$$
$$x^y > y^x \quad  ,x < y \quad \text{ for } x,y>e$$

I can't find a proof without convergence

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#Exponential-like_functions

Comment: What do you call "convergence" in "a proof without convergence"?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  Take the logarithm: $y\ln x<x\ln y$ and consider the function $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}$.

Comment: Ya i did but then, without convergence how??

Comment: Your question sounds as follows: to prove that $f(x)$ has the maximum at $x=e$.